# trying to allow an empty row to the bottom of a input table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form where the user can click on a button that will create a blank row at the bottom of the table. They can click this button for as many rows as they want to add. For some reason, when I click on the button I created, it goes back to my index.php page instead of just adding the row to the current page. Here is some of the code. Please let me know if there is more information that I should be adding here.

Thank you

JavaScript:

```
function new_line() {
var t = document.getElementById("desc_table");
var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
var x = rows[1].cloneNode(true);
x.style.display = "";
r.parentNode.insertBefore(x, r);
}


<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE xhtml>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"><?php //include'css\file.css';?></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/new_line.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="home" onclick="home_btn()">Home</button>

<title>New Estimate</title>

<h1>New Estimate</h1>
<?php
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM entire_info');
$sql -> execute();
$result = $sql ->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows!=0) {
    $entire_info=$result->fetch_assoc();
}
else{
    echo'Cannot find company information<br>';
}
?>
<form>
<table  id="estimate_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <?php 
            echo '<h1>'.$entire_info['name'].'</h1><br>'.
                $entire_info['str_address'].'<br>'.
                $entire_info['city'].', '.$entire_info['province'].' '.$entire_info['postal']
                .'<br>Phone:'.$entire_info['phone'].'<br>Fax:'.$entire_info['fax'].'<br>'.$entire_info['email'].'<br>'; 
        ?>
        <br>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;"><?php echo '<h1>Estimate</h1>'; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                        For:<br>
                        <select name="estimate_for">                            
                        <?php
                        $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM company');

                        $sql -> execute();
                        $result = $sql ->get_result();

                        if ($result->num_rows>0) {
                            while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                $company_name = $row['company'];
                                echo '<option value="'.$company_name.'">'.$company_name.'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            echo'Cannot find company information<br>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         Job:<br> <textarea name="job_name" style="width: 200px ! important;" style="height: 30px ! important;"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;">
            Invoice#: <br>
            Date: <input type="text" name="estimate_date" value="<?php echo date('M d, Y'); ?>">                
        </td>

    </tr>
   </table>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <table id="desc_table">
    <tr>
        <td><font><br><h3>Description</h3></font></td>
        <td><font><h3>Hours</h3></font></td>
        <td><font><h3>Rate</h3></font></td>
        <td><font><h3>Amount</h3></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><textarea name="description" style="width: 400px" style="height: 100px ! important;"></textarea></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="hours"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="rate"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="new_line();">+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>            
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;"><h3>Subtotal</h3></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;"><h3>GST (#87221 2410)
</h3></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="gst"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;"><h3>Total</h3></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is inside a `<form>` so by default it will behave like a submit button.
You have to set its type to a normal button by adding the type attribute:

```
<button onclick="new_line();" type="button">+</button>
```